# Removing index.php on CodeIgniter 2.2.0

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I am running Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 (Oracle VM on Windows 8.1).
Using the PHP phpinfo() function I see mod_rewrite in the apache2handler section under Loaded Modules, so mod_rewrite is enabled.

I made the following changes to my CI config file (application/config/config.php),

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to: $config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; to: $config['uri_protocol']   = 'PATH_INFO';
```

I have tried numerous versions this(.htaccess file located in the root directory of CI ):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

but have yet to get it to work.
What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testsite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: so, do we have to create `.htaccess` file in the root directory? As we know that `.htaccess` file doesn't exist in the root directory of codeigniter 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumption that your folder structure is something like... /var/www/html/testsite and your url is localhost/testsite, then the above rewrite rule will be looking for index.php in /var/www/html and not /var/www/html/testsite.
( /var/www/html will be the default document root. )

So in your equivalent folder of /var/www/html/testsite you can try using the following in your .htaccess file located in /var/www/html/testsite/. so you'd have /var/www/html/testsite/.htaccess with the code...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

All I have done is removed the leading / in the rewrite rule in the last line so it's not heading back to the default document root.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim, but that did not work. My CI is set up in my VM shared directory like this:

    Alias /testsite /media/sf_testsite/
    <Directory "/media/sf_testsite/">
        Options -Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>